# Get the min and max value using sql group by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I used this query for get the total count of Property_SubType using GROUP BY.Now i want to get the Min and Max price for particular Property_SubType form my database how to do it?

Below my query:

```
SELECT Matrix_Unique_ID,Property_Type,Property_SubType,Subdivision, 
        COUNT(*) as count 
FROM ncrmls_mls_res_listings_sorted_2 
WHERE `city`='ABC' 
GROUP BY Property_SubType,Property_Type
```

Comment: Please remove the PHP tag. This question is not related to PHP :-)

Comment: Please give us your `ncrmls_mls_res_listings_sorted_2` table structure.

Comment: the given query will through error as you have not listen Matrix_Unique_ID and Subdivision, in group by clause

Comment: the query is work completely, but i want to get the min and max price value of particular Property_SubType

Comment: I don't think your current query is correct.

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: do you have columns having price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want this query:

```
SELECT Property_Type, Property_SubType, MIN(Price), MAX(Price) 
FROM ncrmls_mls_res_listings_sorted_2 
WHERE city = 'ABC' 
GROUP BY Property_Type, Property_SubType;
```

You appear to be using a (mis)feature of MySQL that allows extra columns in the `SELECT` in an aggregation query.

It occurs to me that you might want full data about the min and max.  If so, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM ncrmls_mls_res_listings_sorted_2 rl JOIn
     (SELECT Property_Type, Property_SubType,
             MIN(Price) as minprice, MAX(Price) as maxprice
      FROM ncrmls_mls_res_listings_sorted_2 
      WHERE city = 'ABC' 
      GROUP BY Property_Type, Property_SubType
     ) pts
     ON pts.Property_Type = rl.Property_Type AND
        pts.Property_SubType = rl.Property_SubType AND
        rl.price IN (minprice, maxprice);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a `MIN()` and `MAX()` function in MySQL. These return the smalles and biggest value for the selected column.

Try something like this (top of my head, not tested):

```
SELECT Matrix_Unique_ID,
  Property_Type,
  MIN(Property_SubType),
  MAX(Property_SubType),
  Subdivision, 
  COUNT(*) as count 
FROM
  ncrmls_mls_res_listings_sorted_2 
WHERE
  `city`='ABC' 
GROUP BY
  Property_SubType, Property_Type
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: You aggregate over a field that you group. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'm not getting it, nevermind. Your comments don't really help me explaining it.