# How to echo the first and last occurrence of time log of the specific date of a specific user id in the <table>?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an html table which is used for viewing the timelog of a user from the userlist. Once a view button is clicked, it will redirect to a page where the first and last timelog of a specific day will appear inside the `<table>`.

Here is an example of the data inside **tbl_timelog** of **db_time**

```
id | user_id   | date        | time  | am_pm
1  | literal01 | Apr 5, 2023 | 09:49 | AM
2  | adlaon05  | Apr 5, 2023 | 09:50 | AM
3  | ong07     | Apr 5, 2023 | 10:01 | AM
4  | literal01 | Apr 5, 2023 | 17:20 | PM
5  | adlaon05  | Apr 5, 2023 | 17:51 | PM
6  | ong07     | Apr 5, 2023 | 18:13 | PM
7  | ong07     | Apr 7, 2023 | 10:11 | AM
8  | literal01 | Apr 7, 2023 | 10:11 | AM
9  | adlaon05  | Apr 7, 2023 | 10:11 | AM
10 | literal01 | Apr 7, 2023 | 10:16 | AM
11 | literal01 | Apr 7, 2023 | 17:12 | PM
12 | ong07     | Apr 7, 2023 | 17:12 | PM
13 | adlaon05  | Apr 7, 2023 | 17:15 | PM
```

Expected output:

user_id: literal01

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|Date   | Apr 5, 2023   | Apr 7, 2023   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Time   | 09:49 | 17:20 | 10:11 | 17:12 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

user_id: adlaon05

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|Date   | Apr 5, 2023   | Apr 7, 2023   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Time   | 09:50 | 17:51 | 10:11 | 17:15 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

user_id: ong07

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+
|Date   | Apr 5, 2023   | Apr 7, 2023   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Time   | 10:01 | 18:13 | 10:11 | 17:12 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

database connection:

```
$server_name = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "db_time";

$connection = mysqli_connect($server_name,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);
```

query:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_timelog` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($query_run){

        $_SESSION['id'] = $user_id;
    }
```

table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <?php 
                $dates = array();
                    foreach($query_run as $row) {
                    if (in_array($row['date'], $dates)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $dates[] = $row['date'];
                    { ?>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2"><?php echo $row['date'];?></th>
            <?php } }?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Time</th>
            <?php 
                $out = array();
                foreach($query_run as $row)
                    {
                        if (in_array($row['am_pm'], $out))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                    $out[] = $row['am_pm'];
                        {?>
            <td><?php echo $row["time"];?></td>
            <?php } }?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the result for each user_id.

user_id: literal01

```
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|Date   | Apr 5, 2023   | Apr 7, 2023 |
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|Time   | 09:49 | 17:20 |
+-------+---------------+
```

user_id: adlaon05

```
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|Date   | Apr 5, 2023   | Apr 7, 2023 |
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|Time   | 09:50 | 17:51 |
+-------+---------------+
```

user_id: ong07

```
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|Date   | Apr 5, 2023   | Apr 7, 2023 |
+-------+---------------+-------------+
|Time   | 10:01 | 18:13 |
+-------+---------------+
```

Timelog is not reflected on Apr 7, 2023.

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even data from the database, [you are still at risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/). If this is a school project. Best time to learn. How to do things right.

Comment: Is the date field have a data type of date? Or is just a string? You  should have date and time in an order by clause. Not a good format for sorting the date. In your second loop. You are using am_pm not date. So it's only going to allow two entries.

Comment: Step one, merge the `date`, `time`, and `am_pm` data to form a single column with datetime values -- this will end the headache that you currently have and then prevent hundreds of headaches in the future.  Then this looks inspiring: [Get Min and Max values with one MySQL query with Group BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50305992/2943403) or [Get the min and max value using sql group by query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298738/2943403) or [SQL : get Min and Max value in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794969/2943403)

Comment: @JasonK - I am using prepared statements to insert those data in the database. What I need is how to display the values with the first and last occurrence of time log of the specific date of a specific user id in the table?

Comment: @mickmackusa - I did merge the date and time, unfortunately, while using the suggested links you have provided, none of them work. Thank you so much for extending your help. I appreciate you for that. But, still it doesn't suit to solve this problem. `$query = "SELECT user_id, MIN(time) AS 'out', MAX(time) AS 'in' FROM tbl_timelog WHERE user_id = '$user_id' GROUP BY user_id";
$query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection)); $log = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run); echo $log['logout']; echo $log['login']`

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($$conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)